# Plot a simple df in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I tried to plot this dataframe in pyspark :

```
+----------+-----+
|      date|count|
+----------+-----+
|1995-03-01|    1|
|1995-06-01|    2|
|1995-07-01|    1|


root
 |-- date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

Here my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [val.count for val in test.select('count').collect()]
x = [val.date for val in test.select('date').collect()]

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.ylabel('Nbre articles')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.title('Nombre articles par mois')
#plt.legend(['asn_val'], loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

But i have an error :

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

I don't find the solution... Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

`count` is a method of `Row`, which means you cannot use the dot notation to get the `count` column. Instead, you can use the square brackets notation, e.g.

```
y = [val['count'] for val in test.select('count').collect()]
x = [val['date'] for val in test.select('date').collect()]
```

You can also use `val[0]` for both cases because getting fields from a `Row` also work with positional indices.